# Why show Undefined variable error in Laravel 5.2?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

First take a look my working file.

**ActionController.php:**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Action;
use App\Role;
use App\Http\Requests;

class ActionController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        //

        $actions = Action::where('id','>=',1)->paginate(10);

        $roles = Role::all();
        $data = ['roles' => $roles];
        return view('actions.index',['actions'=>$actions]);
    }
```

**index.blade.php:**

```
<table id="example2" class="table table-bordered table-hover" width="100%">

    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>URI</th>
            <th>Action</th>
            @foreach($roles as $role)
               <th>{{$role->role}}</th>
            @endforeach
        </tr>
    </thead>
        <tbody>
    @foreach($actions as $action)

        <tr>
            <td>{{$action->uri}}</td>
            <td>{{$action->action}}</td>
            <td>{{$action->role}}</td>
        </tr>

    @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
```

When i trying to show `actions` in `foreach` its working fine but when i want to show `roles` in `foreach` loop then its showing `Undefined variable: roles` error. How can i show the roles in actions index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you were not passing `$roles` variable within your view it should be passed it like as

```
return view('actions.index',['actions'=>$actions])->withRoles($roles);
```

or you can simply pass it like as of `actions`

```
return view('actions.index',['actions'=>$actions,'roles' => $roles]);
```

or

```
$data = ['actions'=>$actions,'roles' => $roles];
return view('actions.index',$data);
```

Answer (score 2):

Change in your `ActionController.php`. You need to create an array you want access in the view, so create an array called `$data` and pass it to the view. After passing array in the view you will be able to access variable you have passed in the controller like you have passed `roles` and `actions` so you can access it by it's name `$roles` and `$actions` from the view.

```
public function index(){
    $actions = Action::where('id','>=',1)->paginate(10);

    $roles = Role::all();
    $data = ['roles' => $roles, 'actions'=>$actions];
    return view('actions.index',$data); // 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
public function index()
{
    //

    $actions = Action::where('id','>=',1)->paginate(10);

    $roles = Role::all();
    return view('actions.index',array('actions'=> $actions, 'roles' => $roles));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not passing the data variable to your view, it should be added to the array you are passing.

```
return view(
    'actions.index',
    [
        'actions' => $actions,
        'roles' => $roles
    ]
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you have same names both for variables and collections, it's better to use [`compact()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.compact.php):

```
return view('actions.index', compact('roles', 'actions'));
```

This will automatically convert names to an array and will pass all the data into the view.

Answer (score 1):

This looks more cleaner. [php compact](http://php.net/manual/en/function.compact.php)

```
return view('actions.index', compact('roles', 'actions'));
```

Comment: Thanks.Its helped.